# How to set up Paypal Payment For Different Users

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, e-commerce

The application i am working have two type of users #1 **Seekers** #2 **Providers**.
**Seekers** will make payments through paypal to **Providers** for completing their work.When both users are agreed to the final price, Seeker will accept the amount and then the paypal payment will take place.Each time i have to pick **Providers** paypal id for final payment.I am not sure how to handle the payment here.Any advice or suggestion would be helpful.

I am curious is there any **wordpress plugin** exist which fulfill the asked requirement ?

Comment: Does the payment flow involve you taking a cut? If so, then you are looking for a payment gateway/merchant account provider that offers something more specialised and I'm not sure PayPal offer this. I'm currently also researching a similar payment system, I'm currently looking into Stripe Connect.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your help..On my application there is no cut, seeker will make payment straight to provider.When seeker press the accept, they will be redirected to the papal payment page as it happens in Paypal Express Checkout